# How do mathematical proofs work?

Tags: soft-question, proof-explanation

How do mathematical "proofs" work? What exactly are you proving? Take for example the pythagorean theorem: a^2 + b^2 = c^2. I looked up some proofs for it and [here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680/Brown/6690/PythaThm.htm) is one article that gives proofs.

First off, I think the equation a^2 + b^2 = c^2 (and even all math equations) is an inferential statement; meaning it is just a statement written in symbols about the observation that "the square root of the sum of the square of the sides of a right triangle is equal to the length of the hypotenuse."

What I mean is someone kept measuring the sides of the right triangles, squared them, added them, then took the square root, and found out that it's equal to the length of the hypotenuse. This was always true, and then using mathematical symbols, they expressed that fact of observation.

For example, in the article I linked, part of the proof for method 1 says,

> The length of each leg of the right triangle is the geometric mean of
>   the lengths of the hypotenuse and the segment of the hypotenuse that
>   is adjacent to the leg

But this also is another fact of observation. But the pythagorean equation itself is a fact of observation, so how can you prove one fact of observation using another fact of observation? You can just say the proof for the pythagorean theorem is that it always works in practice?

Comment: "What exactly are you proving?" Mathematical statements, often written in symbolic form.

Comment: Many mathematical statements, like e.g. arithmetical and geometrical ones are used in "everyday life" : to count colelctions of objects, to measure physical and "practical" magnitudes.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then the proof for the pythagorean theorem is the fact that it works. In fact, no proof is needed since it is an inferential statement.

Comment: A proof is the derivation of a statement from specific axioms (i.e. the axioms assumed as basic facts of the discipline involving the said statement) using rules of logic (and previously proved statements, called theorems).

Comment: Not at all; the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Euclid's_proof) has been proved e.g. by [Euclid (ca.300 BCE, Ancient Greece)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid) for geometrical axioms (see [Euclid's *Elements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements)).

Comment: It might help to *look at an example* of a mathematical proof before asking a question like this. If you google, for example, "proof of the Pythagorean theorem" you'll see some indication of what a mathematical proof consists of. It's not simply "we always see that it works."

Comment: put simply, I'd like to offer the following thought: a proof is an argument. if the argument convinces you, you might call it a proof (to you). so, in math, it is a convincing argument (to you) about 'mathematical stuff' (not 'real-world-examples'). if you want to get more in details, maybe look here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-explanation/#MatExpWitMat https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/

Comment: You can see e.g. Joseph Rotman, [Journey into Mathematics : An Introduction to Proofs](https://books.google.it/books?id=6QDCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: In your second paragraph you state that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is just a symbolic statement of fact. How do you know that is a fact? Are you suggesting that every right triangle was measured?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I just said in the original question that I looked at the proof of the pythagorean theorem. Did you even read? I said: "For example, in the article I linked, part of the proof for method 1 says,"

Comment: @JohnDouma If you measure enough right triangles, then you'll be confident enough to use inductive reasoning to conclude that equation.

Comment: @Kingamere My math background is different than yours so I don't quite understand you. Assume we have measured enough triangles to gain "confidence". (I don't know how many that would be because there are an infinite number of triangles.) Please show me how to use inductive reasoning to finish the proof.

Comment: @Kingamere Inductive reasoning is *not* an accepted form of mathematical proof ("proof by induction," despite the name, is quite different).

Comment: I don't think this question deserves all the downvotes. It's a reasonable question for someone who's confused about the basics to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sketchy history which I hope might help.

It's possible the Babylonians knew a version of Pythagoras' theorem back in 1700
BC—many centuries before Pythagoras—and likely that they did indeed treat it as "a fact of observation".

We know they could work out square roots, and there's a clay tablet with a great long list of Pythagorean triples on it.¹ They seem to have used quite a bit of maths, and they knew from experience that it worked. But there's no evidence of them trying to prove that it *must* work. They seem to have just used it.

What the Greeks did—people like Pythagoras, Euclid, and Archimedes—was set about understanding **why** things like Pythagoras' theorem always worked, and it's really with them that the idea of mathematical proofs began. Euclid's *Elements* is THE classic in this, and was used as a textbook in secondary schools right up to my father's time. Euclid put together a large amount of  mathematics then known, and showed how it all held together.

Euclid started off with a few definitions that were considered so basic that nobody could disagree with them, and some statements that were so obvious and basic that they didn't need to be proved from anything else (and couldn't be anyway).²

The unprovable-but-obvious statements were (and are) called **axioms.** Euclid's included ones like

- Two things which are each equal to the same thing are equal to each other.

What he then did, step by step, was to show logically that if you accepted the definitions and axioms, you had no choice but to accept the various theorems he proved. A mathematical proof of a theorem is basically a demonstration that it inescapably follows either directly from the axioms, or from other things already proved from them.

A proof today doesn't usually start by spelling out the axioms it rests on. They're generally so basic and universally accepted that you'd only need to say if you *weren't* using one or other of them. But it *will* use various other theorems—maybe explicitly, maybe implied by using procedures that rely on them—and ultimately, if the proof is rock-solid, there's a chain we could follow all the way back to the axioms.

---

**Notes**

¹ Another tablet has a square drawn on it. Simplifying slightly, one side of the square is labelled $1$ and the diagonal is labelled with their equivalent of $1.41421$, ie an accurate value of $\sqrt{2}$. (Actually it's written in base $60$, to $3$ base-60 significant figures, and expressed in $60$ths.)

² In fact, one of Euclid's axioms (the "parallel postulate") wasn't at all simple and obvious—but nobody could manage to prove it from the other axioms, and in the nineteenth century it was discovered that assuming it to be *untrue* leads to a whole new kind of geonetry, applicable to curved surfaces and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are no mathematical truths in a metaphysical sense. What's exist is a consistent axiomatic method. Some "facts of observation" are selected as axioms and so called theorems - facts of observations or not - are proved to be consequences of the axioms by using inference rules as modus ponens  and substitution.